# Redirect to different url depending on request url

Tags: php, redirect

I am trying to make a simple redirect php plugin, and i cant get to the bottom, i would really appreciate some help.

Inside a folder i have the php script that will handle the redirect, for ex: /redirect/a.php

Scenario 1:

call /redirect/a.php?key=firstkey the redirect to http://www.url1.com

Scenario 2:
call redirect/a.php?key=secondkey then redirect to http://www.url2.com

General rule:
If a.php is called without key, or with wrong key then display Error.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use global variable `$_GET["key"]` to get value of "?key=value", then use `header()` to redirect.

Note that there cannot be any output before calling `header()`, that applies even for whitespaces (such as space, or tab).

It could look something like this:

```
// checking whether the key is sent by user who visits the page
if(!isset($_GET["key]))
{
die("Key is required");
}

// checking whether the key is empty
if(empty($key) 
{
die("Key shouldn't be empty");
}

if($_GET["key"] == "firstkey")
{
header("location: http://www.url1.com");
}
```

It would be better to use `array()` to list keys that should be accepted by script, you could easily look for them by using `in_array()`.